# Getting duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my application I have `Materials` and `Handlings`, each material can have several handlings.

So, I have a table material, handlings and `handlingMaterial`.

In my edit material view I want to list all existing handlings and check the handlings added to the specific material and my problem is this:

For example:
I have the material:

```
ID | NAME
----------
1  | xpto
```

I have these handlings:

```
ID | Name
-----------------
1  | Temperature
2  | Painting
3  | Anti-humidity
```

And the HandlingMaterial that makes the relation between materials and handlings:

```
ID | ID_HANDLING | ID_MATERIAL
------------------------------
1  | 1           | 1
2  | 3           | 1
```

In this example we can say that material xpto have 2 handlings added.

In my query I want to return this:

```
ID | Name          | HANDLING
------------------------------
1  | Temperature   | 1
2  | Painting      | 0
3  | Anti-humidity | 1
```

But the result is this:

```
ID | Name          | HANDLING
------------------------------
1  | Temperature   | 0
1  | Temperature   | 1
2  | Painting      | 0
3  | Anti-humidity | 0
3  | Anti-humidity | 1


select distinct [u_handling_alb].*, 
    (CASE WHEN u_handlingMaterials_alb.u_material_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS handling 
    from [u_handling_alb] 
    left join [u_handlingMaterials_alb] on [u_handling_alb].[id ] = [u_handlingMaterials_alb].[u_handling_id] 
    where [u_handling_alb].[u_active] = 1
```

Duplicates the results where handling is 1, puts on value with 0 and another with 1. I don't understand why... the error could be in the case.

What is my problem?

Comment: It is worth your while to read enough about SQL and relational database structure to understand why "distinct" is definitely a mistake and how your accepted answer doesn't need it. If nothing else e.g w3schools.com/sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
select h.*, 
       (case hm.u_material_id is not null when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as handling
from u_handling_alb h left join
     u_handlingMaterials_alb hm
     on h.id = hm.u_handling_id and
        hm.u_material_id = 1
where h.u_active = 1
```

Comment: Ok, I update your query case to this and works (case hm.u_material_id when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as handling @GordonLinoff